# Get size of file using blob in google cloud

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-api-python-client

i use this code to get object of file in google cloud.

```
client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json("./credential.json")
   bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket)
   object = bucket.blob(fileurlName)
```

and i have url of file in variable fileurlName, but the results size is none and chunk size is not the same as file size so how can i change it to give me the exact size of file in google cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite tricky.

In fact, when you use the method of the type , you simply ask the client library to build a correct path to access to the object. But you don't access it, you only build a local reference to it. And thus all the value (or almost) are none.

If you want to GET the object, use the get_ method.

In your case replace the `bucket.blob(fileurlName)` by `bucket.get_blob(fileurlName)`. This time, the object metadata are really fetched (the API call is performed) and the size field is populated.